# Session: Everyone in the internet is logged in when a user logs in

Tags: php, session

I have used sessions before but this is weird. I have created a login page and I am using sessions. I am using the following function to check whether a person is logged in:

```
    function check_login() {
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
        $this->user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $this->logged_in = true;
    } else {
        unset($this->user_id);
        $this->logged_in = false;
    }
}
```

However, when the first user logs in, everyone on the internet can access the restricted page with the details of the logged in person. What could I be doing wrong? How should I differentiate the users?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you should show us how you start the session. Also isset means that the variable is set but its value can also be just blank...

Comment: The reason every one can enter because you are just checking whether `$_SESSION['user_id']` is set or not, not its actual value

Comment: When you mean `Everyone on the internet is logged` have you tested it with multiple units or just the same Browser on your unit? Have u tested it on Chrome's `*Incognito*` mode?

Comment: @CarlJan, that is my problem. How do I find the value to compare with the existing session?

Comment: @user3196949 Are they accessing on the same browser? Or with different units?

Comment: @CarlJan, completely different computers. That's my shock.. i have never experienced this before

Comment: If they are using different units, then check for their IP addresses. Although most IPs are dynamic, you will just need to check the current IP of the first user logging in, then block all other IPs

Comment: @CarlJan check the user's IP? if i'm browsing from my office LAN I share the same IP as my collegues. How can you distinguish me from my collegues in this case?

Comment: Have you checked if all of you have the same IP?

Comment: Found the problem. I tested the website using my computer, and stored the session for longer time. After clearing the database and putting the website to real job, the sessions were still there with my user_id, (which is now owned by another person). Resetting my browsers worked for me. Thanks all for your time.